# How does Brief Strategic Therapy (Nardone model) compare to other psychotherapies in efficacy?

Tags: clinical-psychology

Based on Paul Watzlawick et al.'s work in Brief Therapy, Giorgio Nardone & Paul Watzlawick (2005) developed specific protocols for treatment for several distinct psychological disorders, such as panic, phobia, anxiety, OCD, eating disorders etc., which is referred to as [BST - Brief Strategic Therapy (Nardone model)](http://www.centroditerapiastrategica.com/pubblicazione/brief-strategic-therapyphilosophy-techniques-and-research/) .

I have heard anecdotal evidence that BST is superior to other forms of psychotherapy (mainly CBT - cognitive-behavioral-therapy).

Superiority was unspecified in the above conversation, but could be defined as one or more of the following:

- quantitatively greater reduction of symptoms measured as difference between a pre- and a post-treatment test score
- greater persistence of symptom reduction over time
- comparable symptom reduction while more economic (fewer sessions)
- comparable symptom reduction while effective at a greater number of test subjects

I was able to find [one comparative study](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1877042814000068) specific to treating BED (binge eating disorder) and obesity (Pietrabissa et al. 2013, see link above)

**What are the results of studies on the efficacy of BST in comparison to other models of therapy - mainly regarding the most common clusters of diagnosis?**

**References**

Nardone, G. & Watzlawick, P. (2005). *Brief Strategic Therapy: Philosophy, Techniques, and Research*. Lanham, MD: Jason Aronson Inc. ISBN: 978-0765702807

Pietrabissa, G., Manzoni, G. M., Ceccarini, M. & Castelnuovo, G. (2014). A Brief Strategic Therapy Protocol for Binge Eating Disorder. *Procedia - Social and Behavioral Sciences*. 113. 8–15. ([Free PDF](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Giada_Pietrabissa/publication/260213091_A_Brief_Strategic_Therapy_Protocol_for_Binge_Eating_Disorder/links/53e493530cf21cc29fc91245/A-Brief-Strategic-Therapy-Protocol-for-Binge-Eating-Disorder.pdf))
DOI: [10.1016/j.sbspro.2014.01.005](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.sbspro.2014.01.005).

Comment: Welcome to Psychology.SE.  This is an interesting question as I have not heard of this model of therapy so I am doing some research on it.  Looking at [an article on noanxiety.com](http://www.noanxiety.com/psychotherapies/brief-strategic-therapy-giorgio-nardone.html) on the subject, which has no references, it does sound similar to CBT. **The problem with your question as it is written** is that as highlighted in the comments [on Skeptics.SE with your duplicate question](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/40638/43717) questions on superiority is an opinion-based question which gets closed.

Comment: I have just made an edit which I feel is less opinion-based.  I hope it matches what you are after.  Feel free to make further changes where necessary.

Comment: It is a very broad question, you speak of technique (not only of procedure) and that usually involves treating the theoretical framework and effectiveness in all the disorders in which it can be applied ... and it is not a question to speak only of effect size.

Comment: It is still very broad, I am preparing a response with main documents but it is not possible to offer a response of excellent quality comparing the effectiveness of this therapy with others in all the disorders in which it has has been applied.

Comment: @hexadecimal see my edit, tried to narrow the question down